# Best way to handle Content Provider failures in Java Spring Application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have Spring Web Application, which invokes content provider for some data. Its becoming common issue that content provider service is failing and app is becoming unresponsive. What would be best approach or design to check that content provider service is up or down at application level and handle it appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [circuit breaker](https://spring.io/guides/gs/circuit-breaker/) pattern and Hystrix library.

It will monitor the method annotated with `@HystrixCommand` and if the failures amount to a certain threshold, it will start redirecting the calls to a `fallbackMethod`, allowing the continuation of service, and leaving you time to recover from failure.

A simple snippet that shows it in action is as follows:

```
@Service
public class BookService {

  ...

  @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "reliable")
  public String readingList() {
   ...
  }

  public String reliable() {
   ...
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Lets say my CP call is present in many services, do i need to add this for each service ? Can it be configured at application level ?

Comment: yes, the configuration varies though, so its not easy to answer without a bigger context, checkout the https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-To-Use and there's a lot of spring focused usages that for your case may fit better. But, the short answer is yes